# Onclick event finding the most popular post in Blogger

Tags: javascript, xhtml, onclick, blogger, yahoo-pipes

How do I implement the onClick event on my blog menu in such  a way that when the user clicks  the button it will call a javascript function on my blogger template that the gets the most viewed or popular post?

How to implement this snippet below:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function getYpipePP(feed) {
     document.write('<ol style="">');
     var i;
     for (i = 0; i < feed.count ; i++)
     {
        var href = "'" + feed.value.items[i].link + "'";
        var pTitle = feed.value.items[i].title;
        var pComment = " \(" + feed.value.items[i].commentcount + "\)";
        var pList = "<li>" + "<a href="+ href + '" target="_blank">' + pTitle;
         document.write(pList);
         document.write(pComment); //to remove comment count delete this line
         document.write('</a></li>');
     }
     document.write('</ol>');
 }
 </script>
 <script src="http://pipes.yahoo.com/pipes/pipe.run?YourBlogUrl=http://www.MYURL.com&ShowHowMany=10&_id=390e906036f48772b2ed4b5d837af4cd&_callback=getYpipePP&_render=json" 
type="text/javascript"></script>
```

I want to implement this on blogger, but one of my blogs does not support this kind of code. So, my idea is to put an onClick on a link then call a function that contains the modified code above and redirect the user or alike to the most popular post.

Answer (score 0):

Create a `mostPopulars()`-function and call it from `LI`.

```
var pList = "<LI onclick=\"mostPopulars();\">" ...
```

Comment: I am new to javascript sir can you focus your answer in finding the most popular post. Honestly I am really confuse on how to edit the code above. Thank you.

Comment: Sorry, I thought that you have that function already. Without seeing more code it's hard to say anything.